# How restore an imploded popup in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

In the preferences you can check the checkbox "Show variable and type declarations in a popup", under  User Interface -> Code assistant. What this does is it shows a popup when you hover over a variable or type in the code. It worked fine, but now I got an minimized popup. Is there a way get the popup to normal size?

Red arrow my PL/SQL developer

Green arrow what it should look like

[image: PL/SQL screenprint]

Comment: Just try to close the PL/SQL developer from Task bar and relaunch it again.

Comment: Unfortionally that doesn't help

Comment: ohh okay. Are you able to increase the size of pop-up with mouse pointer?

Comment: @SachinPadha that was my first thought, but there is no mouse grab bar or other interactive resizing option for these (as there is for autocompletion for example).

Comment: @EbertZ this seems to be more of a support question for the vendor rather than a tool use issue for SO. I suggest posting it on their helpful support forum, https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=postlist&Board=3&page=1

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks for the advise. I just posted the question on the Allround automations forum

Comment: Today I tried some things to get plsql developer working again te right way. I got it working without problems, a popup with filling. 

I have 3 screen to work with, they are in the order left to right 2,3,1, On screen 1 (main screen) everything works fine. I get the popup with filling, on screen 2 nothing is shown and on screen 3 I get an empty popup. Does anyone knows what can cause the problem?